# Is there enough to working with Spring Boot if I known to perform CRUD Operation?

Tags: spring-boot, crud

I am a completely fresher for Spring Boot. I had learn to perform Basic CRUD operations using REST API. That basic knowledge is enough to working with Spring Boot Project. Can I able to work with that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**No one is technically perfect!**

Every day we are exploring new things and implement new solutions as per the new business requirements. The developer should possess a good set of problem-solving skills. That’s because it’s common for developers to come across multiple programming problems while building just about any solution.

If your lead assigned a task to you explore quarkus and implement a simple CRUD operation using go language what you will do?

"I don't know golang", Is this your answer?

---

**Qualities of a good junior software programmer**

- Learn new things daily which must be useful to the growth of the company, your team and you.
- Problem Solving and Logical Thinking
- Written and Verbal Communication
- Teamwork
- Interpersonal skills
- Time management
- How do I search for answers from StackOverflow like a PRO?  This is a very important skill set, Really, I am not joking.
- Health - Health(Physical/Mental) is an important asset, don't take official things personally. Manage stress etc...

---

**Coming to technical side**

It would be good if you know at least one programming language, in your case java is fine. But if you have the listed skill sets you can learn anything very easily.

**Regarding Spring boot**

Do you want to become an expert in the Spring framework? Work with one big project, whatever domain.

**Refer** - https://www.baeldung.com/

**Once you become pro** - Refer - https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/

Answer (score 1):

As a starter this is fine, but if your application is going to face real customers/users and want to evolve your application over time, then you would need to consider concepts like below

- Login/logout security with Spring Security (if stateless then JWT is a good choice)
- Evolving code and database with versions of your software (can use Liquibase to evolve and maintain DB changes ).
- Handling exceptions as Aspects from Spring.
- Having coded business errors so your team can resolve them and classify them accordingly.

Comment: @muthuarasan is your application facing clients?